# Link two combo boxes Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to link two comboboxes ! In the first combo box I have the names of some states in greece and in the other the cities ! In the second I have all the cities in Greece and I want when I select a state from the first combo box only certain cities to appear on the second !  For example if I select Attikis , then I want to be shown in dropdown menu only Agias Paraskeuis and not Agias Varvaras and Agiou Dimitriou and vice versa !

My code is this :

```
<form action="?" method="get">
    <div class="jtype">
        <label for="nomos"> Νομός </label> 
        <form name="nomoi_poleis" action="">
            <select id="combo_nomoi" name="combo_nomoi" onchange="cityChange()" > 
                <option value="attikis"> Attikis</option>
                <option value="thessalonikis"> Thessalonikis</option> 
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <label for="poli">Πόλη</label>
            <select id="poleis" name="poleis">
                <option value="agias varvaras"> Agias Varvara</option>
                <option value="agias paraskeuis">Agias Paraskeuis</option>
                <option value="agiou dimitriou"> Agiou Dimitriou</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ana my JS :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeCity(){
                var nomos = document.getElementById("combo_nomoi");
                if (nomos.value == "attikis"){
                    document.getElementById("attikis");
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("thessalonikis");
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: where is your javascript?

Comment: and please dont use nested form elements! (remove one form)

Comment: Just added my JS, I had forgotten !

Answer (score 0):

0The easiest way is to have a set of `<select>` menus, all but one of which has its `display` property set to `none`, with the one you want to display set to `inline`. Then in your `onchange` handler you run through your list of selects in a loop, setting the `display` property accordingly. Note inline event handlers like that are not very good practice; better to set them up via JavaScript in your page initialisation code. It misght look something like:

(HTML)

```
<select id="states">
   <option value="0" selected="selected">State 1</option>
   <option value="1">State 2</option>
   ...
</select>

<select id="cities_0" style="display: inline;">
   <option value="...">Name 1</option>
   <option value="...">Name 2</option>
   ...
</select>

<select id="cities_1" style="display: none;">
   <option value="...">Name 1</option>
   <option value="...">Name 2</option>
   ...
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
function change_city(evt)
{
var states=document.getElementById('states'),whichstate;

whichstate=states.options[state.selectedIndex].value;

for(var i=0;i<states.options.length;i++)
   document.getElementById('cities_'+i).style.display=(i==whichstate ? 'inline' : 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a crude example(using only JS) to get this working:

http://jsfiddle.net/FMZ2H/

HTML

```
<form action="?" method="get">
<div class="jtype">
    <label for="nomos">Νομός</label>
    <form name="nomoi_poleis" action="">
        <select id="combo_nomoi" name="combo_nomoi">
            <option value="attikis">Attikis</option>
            <option value="thessalonikis">Thessalonikis</option>
        </select>
        <br></br>
        <label for="poli">Πόλη</label>
        <select id="poleis" name="poleis">
            <option id="option1" value="agias varvaras">Agias Varvara</option>
            <option id="option2" value="agias paraskeuis">Agias Paraskeuis</option>
            <option id="option3" value="agiou dimitriou">Agiou Dimitriou</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("combo_nomoi").onchange = cityChange
function cityChange() {
   var elem = document.getElementById("combo_nomoi");
   if (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text == "Attikis") {
      document.getElementById("option1").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("option2").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("option3").disabled = false;
   }
   if (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text == "Thessalonikis") {
      document.getElementById("option1").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("option2").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("option3").disabled = true;
   }
}
```

As shown above, you could disable the options you don't want your user to select. I'll leave it to you to do it an better way than selecting each option by their id.